# Get both ID and Name from a field of type 'Person or Group' in a Content Query web part

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180825/get-both-id-and-name-from-a-user-type-field-in-a-cqwp) on StackOverflow a couple of weeks ago, but since it hasn't got very much attention I'm posting it here instead.

---

I'm building a Content Query Web Part that is supposed to show a link to a user page (userdisp.aspx). I get the user name from a custom list containing a column named 'Member' of the type 'Person or Group'.

[image]

To build the link in the ItemStyle.xsl, I need both the name and the Id of the user:

```
<a href="http://<site>/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=@ID">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Name" />
</a>
```

However, I'm only able to get the name OR the Id from the Content Query. E.g. if I set "Show field: Name (with presence)" for the Member column I get the name, and if I set "Show field: ID" I obviously get the Id. But I need both!

[image]

[image]

I should probably also point out that I'm building the solution on a very stripped down version of SharePoint, so all I have to play with is .xsl and .webpart files, and whichever settings I can make in the online editor (no access to SharePoint Designer).

Last but not least, my SharePoint knowledge level is noob. :)

Comment: I know this is an older post. But I still have this problem. I would like to add additional fields of the field person (ID, name, workphone, email) to CQWP. I can't find a solution. Are there any alternative workarounds. Also in the list one can not over Lookup or Calculated to the Infos come. Looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. I doesn't solve the original problem (getting both Name and ID) - it proposes another solution.

Instead of trying to get both Name and ID (I thought I needed the ID to build the URL to the member's page), I used the following to look up the URL of the member:

```
<xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
        <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

So instead of this:

```
<a href="http://<my_site>/sites/<my_sub_site>/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID={@ID}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Member" />
</a>
```

I ended up with this

```
<a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Member" />
</a>
```

in the itemstyle.xsl. Much cleaner - and it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

Technically the People Picker column values are a span with a BUNCH of attributes stuck to it. Here is normally how I get the two main basics from it:

ID => `<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(@PickerColumn, 'ID='), '&amp;')" />`

Display Name => `<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(@PickerColumn, '&gt;'), '&lt;')" />`

Haven't used the last one in a while so let me know if it doesn't work. Hope that helps!

Comment: Well, that's what I thought too, but it seems that when passing the column to a Content Query web part, you can only get one (1) of the attributes. When I do the same thing for a Link type column, I'm able to get comma separated attributes: `URL = http://google.com, Google Search`

Comment: I've added an image to the question, showing the "Show field" selection that affects which attribute is sent to the content query. I'd like an "All attributes as comma separated values" option! :)

Comment: Just tried the Display Name expression above on SP 2016 (on premises) and it does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me :

```
<xsl:value-of select="@PersonColum.title" />      ----- for Name 
<xsl:value-of select="@PersonColum.id" />         ----- for id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment to @T0t3sMcG0t3s post but don’t have enough rep. Here is the XSLT I used to get the display name of the group or person field.

```
substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(@AssignedTo, 'GoToLinkOrDialogNewWindow(this)'),'&gt;'),'&lt;')
```